insert a pyhon formula in an excel file using python (xmlwriter write_formula)
I'm automating the generation of multiple files using python. I know how to export the file with normal excel formulas, but i want to see whether i can insert PYTHON code that can be interpreted inside excel (I have 365 with python on excell).
I mean xmlwriter write_formula but a python formula.
thanks in advance
